# Manually creating computer account and SPN's in Kerberos (krb5) keytab file for Window Active Directory domain

Tags: linux, active-directory, kerberos

Lots of articles on the net describes how you can join a Linux box to a Windows Active Directory domain, some using "realmd", some using samba and so forth. Others describe how you can do things manually without using `realm join` or `net ads join` and so on. When I look at a kerberos keytab file (via `ktutil`) that was automagically generated by these ad joining utilities, I see entries like `COMPUTER$DOMAIN.EXAMPLE.COM` (note the dollar sign).

But if I follow articles that describe how you can do things manually (not using `realmd`, etc), such as creating keytabs using the `ktpass` command (Windows AD), `setspn`, and creating the service principles (such as `RestrictedKrbHost/domain.example.com` and `HOST/domain.example.com`, etc), then these keytab files don't contain these `COMPUTER$DOMAIN.EXAMPLE.COM` entries. Not sure if I have skipped something or misstepped, but it seems, when using utilities like `ktpass` on Windows, I cannot create these kind of entries manually, or I don't know how.

**Question:** How do automatic utilities (like realmd) work to create these`COMPUTER$DOMAIN.EXAMPLE.COM` entries in the keytabs, or put another way, how can I create them manually (Linux- or Windows-AD-side) if I do not use such utilities? Looking through the realmd sources is leaving my head a bit dizzy. (https://github.com/freedesktop/realmd/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The tool I was looking for is called "**msktutil**", by Dan Perry and others (https://github.com/msktutil/msktutil). It can create the keytabs I was looking for (`COMPUTER$@DOMAIN.EXAMPLE>COM`). A man page (Ubuntu) is here: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man1/msktutil.1.html

It's a useful tool when you want to script docker images/containers that need to integrate with Windows Active Directory, while avoiding SSSD and mount-binding the host /var/lib/sss/pipes directory as data volume to the container. This utility also allows me to keep things nicely in sync with AD.